# Attachment removed from e-mail when sent via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-office-365

We have a custom backoffice application that sends out e-mails to clients through the Microsoft Graph API. These e-mails are transactional but standardized, like reservation confirmations, or asking someone to fill out a standard form.

Now we've noticed that with one specific e-mail - that is always sent with two attachments - one of the attachments is removed. It's not replaced by a textfile that warns the user about a missing attachment, it's just removed all together. When we switch to an SMTP provider and send the exact same e-mail, both attachments land in the same recipient e-mail box that was used testing the Graph API. Are there any security checks we can disable to stop this from happening?

Comment: You might want to debug the email by trying to send attachments with different file extensions.  You might be able to come up with one that you can use.